# useradd creates home directory owned by root

Tags: docker, useradd

I'm using the following command to create a user and home directory, but for some reason, the newly created home directory is owned by root:

```
useradd --user-group --create-home --base-dir /opt --shell /bin/bash testuser
```

I'm creating a Docker image based on eclipse-temurin:11.0.15_10-jre-focal (based on Ubuntu 20.04). The command above is included in my Dockerfile, and the strange thing is that when I build it locally on my Windows box, the home directory is owned by the new user, but when I build it with an Azure,, DevOps pipeline, the home directory is owned by root. I don't understand what would cause the useradd command to behave differently.
I found posts with a similar issue related to the home directory being on NFS volumes, but it's not the case here: /opt is inside the container.

Comment: Maybe you should be using adduser instead, it's a little user friendlier.  See the man pages, man adduser.

Comment: I did but I get the same behavior. Local build: home directory is owned by testuser. Azrue DevOps build: home directory is owned by root.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with docker.io on Ubuntu 22.04, with this simple Dockerfile,

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -s /bin/bash xyz && ls -l /home
RUN ls -l /home
```

the ownership of the `xyz` homedir got set to root:root between the `RUN` commands. I found a solution in setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`,

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

Maybe you can define or set that in your Azure pipeline.

Comment: For compatibility with Ubuntu 20.04, you might also need `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1` to make docker use BuildKit.

Comment: https://www.docker.com/blog/faster-builds-in-compose-thanks-to-buildkit-support/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and ended up fixing it by doing a clean re-install of Docker. I followed [this](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/ubuntu-uninstall-docker/) guide to uninstall completely (except didn't need to delete docker group). Then followed the [regular docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the one metioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/+bug/2029523/). The bug is fixed in `docker.io` version `20.10.25-0ubuntu1~20.04.2` / `20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.2`.

Updates:

- Focal (20.04): [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1~20.04.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1%7E20.04.2)
- Jammy (22.04): [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1~22.04.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io-app/20.10.25-0ubuntu1%7E22.04.2)